# inclusion of $C^{\infty}$ to B-spaces $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

if the function is $C^{\infty}(D)$, does it imply that this function is also in all of the $L^p$ spaces as well?

Edit: I am looking at $u_t=x^2u_{xx}+yu_y, \; D=[0,1]\times[0,1]\times [0,T]$. I can see from degenerate theory the weak solution (bounded measurable) exist. And I can use Hormander theory that tells me that the solution is actually infinitely smooth. So I wonder if I can deduce some integrability properties.

Comment: What is true is that for $1 < p < \infty$, ${\cal C}_c(G)$ is a dense subspace of ${\cal L}^p(G)$ if $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^d}$.

Comment: A $C^\infty$ function is in particular continuous, and a continuous function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,T]$ is in all $L^p$ spaces because a continuous function on a compact space is bounded and the measure space has finite measure, if I understand the question correctly.